# Does the story of Dragon Quest continue after the anime?

Tags: dragon-quest-adventure-of-dai

I'm watching the animated remake version of Dragon Quest so I also started to watch the 1991-1992 anime version. I've read the anime version lasted 1 year on air (49 episodes, 1 per week) when the manga lasted 7 years. Does this mean there is more story after the 1991-1992 anime? Or they just compressed the story a lot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Quest:_The_Adventure_of_Dai#First_series_(1991)) (with a source):

> The series adapts the events of the first 10 volumes of the manga, with initial plans to continue onward until scheduling and time slot changes at TBS lead to the series ending after 46 episodes. To accommodate the abrupt ending, [Riku] Sanjo [the manga's author] helped to provide an adjusted finale to the anime.

The manga apparently has 37 volumes, so yes, the story continues for a considerable amount past the point where the anime stopped.